# Innovation behind formula for surface area and volume of a sphere

Tags: calculus, volume, area, spheres

When I saw some problems about innovation behind area of a circle in this site, I was wondering that about a sphere. We know volume of sphere is $\frac{4}{3}\pi\cdot r^3$ and surface area is $4\pi\cdot r^2$, but how did Archimedes find these relation? Of course we can find this relation using vector calculus with rigorous integration,but those days Newton wasn't born,right?!!!! Also you can measure area of circle by inscribing a polygon and then Think what would happen when side of polygon is too large, but for a sphere (a 3 dimensional object), that is difficult... Also when surface area come to picture, difficulty increase tremendously (a curved area is coming), then by what method he found out these relation which is so fundamental to geometry? What was his innovative idea for finding this relations??
Thank you.

Comment: Yes,but how about a 3-D solid??

Comment: There is a brilliant explanation by James Tanton on [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=npG4MwDmDDc) worth to watch!

Answer (score 1):

There is an argument from first principles using a geometric construction.
You can see it here, for example: mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.01/rahul1.html

Comment: How can I assume volume of con as??!

Comment: @Half-Bloodprince Also a standardized summation of simple shapes argument. Here is an example of derivation using a method of disks (which I don't like): http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55263.html

Comment: @Half-Bloodprince You should be able to find easily the geometric proof that the cone is 1/3 the volume of the circumscribing cylinder.

Comment: @Half-Bloodprince here is the original Euclid's proof of that fact: http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookXII/propXII10.html

Answer (score 1):

Archimedes developed the Law of of the Lever which used very thoughtfully.

Read the whole story: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBEoD.png)

[image]

Comment: But how did this law proved?also how to prove the volume of cone is $\frac{1}{3} \pi r^3$. ??

Comment: To prove the cone all you have to have is pi and the formula for calculating the area of a triangle. The law of the lever is just about balancing the equations(eg. $2y=1/3x$). If you know the distance and the mass of the other object you can prove that the law holds with an experiment.